# Using parameter into a select query

Tags: c#, mysql, parameters

I have this query, which works perfect in the codeline and in my *MySQL Manager*:

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3
FROM Mytable
WHERE date_start >= STR_TO_DATE(' 01/07/2014 ', '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Now, in the *CodeBehind* using *parameter* it doesn't return a single row...

```
sql = @"SELECT field1, field2, field3
    FROM Mytable
    WHERE date_start >= STR_TO_DATE('@data', '%d/%m/%Y')"

MySQLCOMMAND.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@data", MySqlDbType.Date)).Value = data;
```

Where data = 01/07/2014.

Why it doesn't work with parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Your parameter is already a date.  You don't need to convert it:

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3
FROM Mytable
WHERE date_start >= @data;
```

Comment: I HAVE TO use *STR_TO_DATE* as the value I'm passing, isn't in the format *yyyy/mm/dd*.

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro . . . The value that you are passing is a date as defined by `MySqlDbType.Date`.  The conversion is done at the application layer not at the database layer.

Comment: I don't know man, but without *STR_TO_Date*, it returns me every row on the database =s not just those included in the filter =s

Comment: The query you're using in MySQL Manager is not equivalent to the query you're generating in C#, because the type you're using in C# is already a Date - if you want to pass a string parameter as the database type, you should use VarChar or Text as the MySqlDbType.

Comment: If you need it in yyyy/mm/dd format try using `DateTime.TryParseExact` method shown in example 3 here [http://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-tryparse](http://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-tryparse)